# How to use Kendo UI in Sitefinity's MVC Widget?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, sitefinity

How can we use Kendo UI in Sitefinity's MVC Widgets?

I read that we need to use CDN to use Kendo UI with Sitefinity MVC Widgets but I've Try it and the HTMLHelper 'Kendo' Is not Recognized.

Which steps should we take to use kendo ui and its Helpers in Sitefinity MVC widgets(razor views)?

I've done multiple things that was install and trying to configure the project to use kendo ui. but as sitefinity comes with kendo libraries I leaved that approach because it seems incorrect.

I've also tried to use cdn to charge the libraries but the kendo helpers were not load. Probably I'm missing somehthing. Kendo Ui Helpers probably are in the Server Side but I don't know how to use them in sitefinity

Any Help with code or defined steps would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, and it was simpler than I was thinking.
To user the Kendo UI Html Helpers I just needed to:

1- get the Kendo.Mvc.Ui.dll

2- add reference in my project

3- Import the dll @using kendo.Mvc.Ui in the top of the view

4- add cdn references so that you can avoid conflicts with other sitefinity's widgets

Done

Comment: I am getting an error kendo.syncReady is not a function is that related to the Import the dll @using kendo.Mvc.Ui in the top of the view

Comment: I don't know Jefferson, I'm no longer using Kendo. Try open a question in stackoverflow and someone will very likely help you. Cheers